# Jquery UI can not work with 1.12version

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I use jQuery UI in my project. The version of jquery-ui.min.css and jquery-ui.min.js are both v1.12. So I choose the latest version of jQuery jquery-3.2.1.min.js.

And I choose datepicker() to test. But it worked fail. When i cilick the input text, there is nothing appear.Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <title>jQueryUI</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jsui/jquery-ui.min.css">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jsui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jsui/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
   <script>
     $(function(){
       $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
     });
   </script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And I had tried jQuery.min.js of 1.9 version, but it also worked fail. I don't know where is wrong? Who can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load jQuery before jQuery-ui.

Try in this order.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jsui/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsui/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

In the below snippet, I used CDNs.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.2.2/jquery.form.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" />
</div>
```